# Why doesn't the button disable code work?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement the functionality of disabling a button. Until 10 characters are entered in the field, it is gray and disabled, when there are 10 characters in the field, it turns blue and causes an alert. But for some reason this example does not work. Can someone suggest why?

```js
final TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();
  bool _showIcon = false;
  bool isEnabled = false;

  // show alert on click
  void callbackfunction(){
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Simple Alert"),
      content: Text("This is an alert message."),
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   TextField(
                onChanged: (String value) {
                if (value.length == 10){
                  setState(()=> isEnabled = true);
                } else {
                  isEnabled = false;
                }
                  setState(() {
                    _showIcon = value.isNotEmpty;
                  });
                },
                controller: _inputController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
                  ),
                  hintText: "(1201) 565-0123 ",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                  helperText: 'Enter your phone number',
                  helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                  suffixIcon: _showIcon
                      ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _inputController.clear();
                        _showIcon = false;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.grey),
                  )
                      : null,
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
              ),
             Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
               children: [
                 ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: () {
                        isEnabled == true ? callbackfunction : null;
                     },
                     child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded, size: 25),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                       shape: CircleBorder(),
                       padding: EdgeInsets.all(15)
                   )
                 ),
               ],
             )
)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the way you define the `onPressed` attribute

Try

```
onPressed: isEnabled ? callbackfunction : null,
```

In the previous way, you define always a function and the check on it will result always to not be null

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help, when I enter 10 characters, the button does not work

Comment: is the `onChanged` working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Since you using masket formatter you have to count them as well so your validation length would be 18 if you using the default example from the plugin page:

```
var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '+# (###) ###-##-##', filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')}, type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy);
```

on change validation:

```
onChanged: (String value) {
  if (value.length == 18) {
    setState(() => isEnabled = true);
  } else {
    isEnabled = false;
  }
  setState(() {
    _showIcon = value.isNotEmpty;
  });
},
```

Change color your elevated button when its valid:

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  primary: isEnabled ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
),
```